# Aframe.js, shadow="receive: false", don't display occlusion map on the second uvset

Tags: aframe, gltf

**Description:**

- A-Frame Version: 1.1.0
- Platform / Device: PC

Hello,

if a glb model have `shadow="receive: false"`, Aframe don't display occlusion map on the second uvset. Work with `shadow="receive: true"`.
why? it's a bug?
I would like use occlusion map to bake my lightmap, so don't use realtime shadow for this model.
edit : but I want keep my light for other models with realtime shadow, like character, just want some models don't receive light if I  use a occlusionmap/lightmap.

How Can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AO affects only ambient light sources. Your AO maps may not have any effects if your scene does not have any ambient light.

You can easily try to debug and narrow down the issue if you remove any other maps (textures, normals):

```
// assuming element has the gltf-model component
element.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
  const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
  mesh.traverse(node => {
    if (!node.material) return;
    node.material.map = null; // remove the texture 
    node.material.normalMap = null; // remove the normalmap
  })
})
```

So you actually see only the effects of the AOMap - like i did [here](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-gftruj-ao). You can see that the model with `shadow="receive: false"` has its ambient occlusion map applied.

Comment: Without a sample glitch it's hard to say what's wrong, so here's a wild guess + a working example.

Comment: @TURTLE did the example help? Is it working differently than Your scene?

Comment: yeah very helpfull, I undertsand occlusion map is only visible in the shadow area unlike a lightmap. thanks

Comment: @TURTLE glad i could help, if you dont have further questions feel free to mark the answer